# Why does the Apache create much more rotor noise than the A-129?

Tags: helicopter, noise, ah-64

The AH-64 Apache attack helicopter was upgraded several times after its first flight in 1974. The Apache Longbow was a major upgrade which [entered service in 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_AH-64_Apache#AH-64D). On the other hand, Agusta A-129's [first flight was in 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agusta_A129_Mangusta).

I have two questions:

1. Why does AH-64D have much [high rotor noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26eqFN1BB70)? Why wasn't there any effort to suppress the noise in the upgraded versions?
2. Why does A-129 have [lower rotor noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGXryOj7Nf4) (i.e. the chop chop sound is almost absent) even though its tail rotor isn't covered?

Comment: For what it's worth you're comparing apples to oranges - the Apache is roughly twice as powerful (with twice the payload) as the Mangusta, and it's about 50% larger in most meaningful specifications. Also, comparing two youtube videos is about as unscientific as you can get from a noise standpoint - different microphones, different environments, etc.

Comment: @egid - if indeed the engines are as you say, then that serves as an answer and I'd recommend posting one. Noise is directly proportional to thrust / rotor lift after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they are very different helicopters, as egid already pointed out.

- The Apache is twice as heavy as the Mangusta (5165 kg vs 2530 kg empty)
- The rotor diameter is also bigger accordingly (14.6 m vs 11.9 m)

A Chinook transport will make more noise than an Apache. An Apache will make more noise than a Mangusta. Different helicopters and different weights that have to be kept airborne.